# How to calculate logistic deviance with pipes?

Tags: pipe, magrittr

In base `R` if I have a vector of probabilities `p`, I can calculate the deviance as

`-2 * sum(p * log(p) + (1-p) * log(1-p))`

How would you write that in magrittr pipes?